# Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\nwrs8-20-2015\cms\login.php on line 9

Tags: php, apache, header

When I run the code it gives me this warning:

> "Warning: Header may not contain more than a single header, new line detected in C:\xampp\htdocs\nwrs8-20-2015\cms\login.php on line 9"

It won't let me continue on or redirect me to the page I'm trying to get. It doesn't do this if I take away the last else, so I'm thinking that maybe it's sending 2 headers instead of just one. From what I can tell there isn't a newline in the code anywhere, so I'm stumped. I searched through some other questions, but they didn't seem that relevant to what I'm doing. I actually got this code snippet from a reputable book publisher Wrox: Beginning PHP, MYSQL, and Apache Web Development.

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['logged'] = 0;

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if($_POST['username'] == "sandra" &&
    $_POST['password'] == "MotherOf4") {
    $_SESSION['logged'] = 1;
    header("Refresh: 5; URL=" . $_POST['redirect'] . "");
    echo "You are being redirected to your original page request!<br>";
    echo "(If your browser doesn't support this, " .
         "<a href=\"" . $_POST['redirect'] . "\">Click here</a>)";
} else {
if (isset($_GET['redirect'])) {
$redirect = $_GET['redirect'];
} else {
  $redirect = "../index.php";
}   
include('halfShellTop.php');
?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect"
value="<?php echo $_GET['redirect']; ?>">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<?php

include('halfShellBottom.php');
    }
} else {
    ?>
<form action="login.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="redirect"
value="<?php echo $_GET['redirect']; ?>">
Username: <input type="text" name="username"><br>
Password: <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have mismatched quotes, assign the POST[] to a variable and use the variable instead

```
$redir = $_POST["redirect"]
header("Refresh: 5; URL='$redir'");
```

Comment: I think I discovered the problem. If I submit the first else{} clause it goes through just fine, because it's getting the redirect variable from that page, however if I click through to the second else{} clause the $_GET['redirect'] variable goes away. How can I make the $_GET['redirect'] go through to the next else clause?

Answer (score 0):

It was a case of the pesky $_POST. What happened was I realized that the redirect $_GET['redirect'] was being put inside of a posted statement in the second else{}. So basically I had to change the $_GET['redirect'] to $_POST['redirect']. My advice is for people to be careful and pay attention to whether they're using $_POST or $_GET. It can get confusing fast.